# Eclipse on Ubuntu - multiple installation

Tags: installation, eclipse

I need to install 2 version of Eclipse. One for Java and one for PHP. Should I expect that some hidden folder/file is gonna be overridden by both installation?
I downloaded to standalone installation package from the eclipse download page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse installation is actually a zip file that can be extracted into some folder of your choice. You may have two Eclipse installed by naming the directories with a different name (e.g. eclipse_java and eclipse_php).
There is no problem with that because Eclipse doesn't store anything outside of its directory and the Workspace directory.

Comment: I do have a .eclipse folder in my /home

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you don't need to have separate Eclipse installations for different environments. The [persepctive](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-25.htm) concept is made to switch from different tasks, and you can easily download different [plugins](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/install_plugin/index_v35.html).

Comment: yeah that's absoluely true but since I'm gonna need in total like 9 plugins, if I install them on the same installation it's gonna be slow, trust me. I usually keep separated installation for every language to keep the bootstrap thin.

Comment: Like Yossile said - if you change your Workspace folder you're changing your set of plugins ( check <workspace_name>/.metadata/.plugins ). You should be fine with a single installation and 2 workspaces.